# ggplot2: coloured vertical lines

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'd like to create a ggplot graph with vertical lines of different colors. Here one way to achieve this goal.

```
mtcars$colors = rep(1:4, nrow(mtcars)/4)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=subset(mtcars, colors==1)$wt, color="red") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=subset(mtcars, colors==2)$wt, color="blue") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=subset(mtcars, colors==3)$wt, color="yellow") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=subset(mtcars, colors==4)$wt, color="green")
```

[image]

This solution is not very handy when the variable `colors` takes 50 different values 1) because it asks the user to write a very long expression (or to construct the ggplot object iteratively) and 2) because it does not produce legends for the colors. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this instead:

```
+ geom_vline(aes(xintercept = wt,color = factor(colors))) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red','blue','yellow','green'))
```

Comment: Oh well.. that was easy! Thank you Joran