# when ggplot legend is for both geom_vline and geom_hline, what determines the order of the type of lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

y <- rnorm(100)

df <- tibble(y) %>% 
  mutate(os = factor(rep_len(1:5, 100)),
         date = seq(from = ymd('2013-01-01'), by = 1, length.out = 100))

draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (data$colour %in% c("red", "blue"))
    draw_key_vpath(data, params, size)
  else
    draw_key_path(data, params, size)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = y, colour = os)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(
    aes(xintercept = min(date), linetype = 'os 1'), 
    colour = 'red', key_glyph = "cust") +
  geom_vline(
    aes(xintercept = median(date), linetype = 'os 2'), 
    colour = 'black', key_glyph = "cust") +
  geom_hline(
    aes(yintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed"), 
    colour = "blue", key_glyph = "cust"
  ) +
  geom_hline(
    aes(yintercept = -1, linetype = "dashed 2"), 
    colour = "purple", key_glyph = "cust"
  ) +

  scale_linetype_manual(
    name = 'lines',
    values = c(2, 2, 1, 1),
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c('red', 'black', 'blue', "purple"))))
```

output:

[image]

In the legend, the 2 vertical lines are supposed to be on top while the 2 horizontal lines are supposed to be on the bottom.

How to control that?

Comment: You can explicitly set `breaks = c("dashed", "os 1", "dashed 2", "os 1")` in the linetype scale.

Comment: Legend key order can be a reason to pass a named vector of values to `values` in a manual scale function a la `values = c("os 1" = 2, "os 2" = 2, "dashed" = 1, "dashed 2" = 1)`.

Comment: @aosmith that did not work. it did reorder the labels, but the linetypes are still uncontrollable, v, h, v, h. it should be v, v, h, h

Comment: @teunbrand that did not work

Comment: I think the v, h, v, h is because of your `draw_key()` function, where you put a vertical line if the color is red or blue.  I switched that to red and black to match your plot and thought things looked fine: `if (data$colour %in% c("red", "black"))`

Answer (score 1):

Part of the solution regarding the **order of keys** was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306782/how-do-i-add-a-legend-to-identify-vertical-lines-in-ggplot/56307774). The default order is alphabetic, but you can set the order using `limits`, and you can use pairs to define the corresponding linetype in `values` (otherwise it gets confusing with the re-ordering).

However, I have *no solution* yet to change the **vertical/horizontal layout of the keys**. There is a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954248/how-to-change-the-orientation-of-the-key-of-a-legend-in-ggplot), which shows that specific key aspects can be changed by applying `grid::editGrob` to the `ggplot` object, but it looks a bit daunting.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

set.seed(123)

y <- rnorm(100)

df <- tibble(y) %>% 
  mutate(os = factor(rep_len(1:5, 100)),
         date = seq(from = ymd('2013-01-01'), by = 1, length.out = 100))

draw_key_cust <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (data$colour %in% c("red", "blue"))
    draw_key_vpath(data, params, size)
  else
    draw_key_path(data, params, size)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = y, colour = os)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(
    aes(xintercept = min(date), linetype = 'os 1'), 
    colour = 'red', key_glyph = "cust") +
  geom_vline(
    aes(xintercept = median(date), linetype = 'os 2'), 
    colour = 'black', key_glyph = "cust") +
  geom_hline(
    aes(yintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed"), 
    colour = "blue", key_glyph = "cust"
  ) +
  geom_hline(
    aes(yintercept = -1, linetype = "dashed 2"), 
    colour = "purple", key_glyph = "cust"
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    name = 'lines',
    values = c("os 1" = 1,
               "os 2" = 1,
               "dashed" = 2,
               "dashed 2" = 2),
    limits = c("os 1","os 2", "dashed", "dashed 2"),
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = c('red', 'black', 'blue', "purple"))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: that's not the desired outcome. the legend is supposed to display in order v, v, h, h. what you have is v, h, v, h

Comment: I know, but at least the labels and colours are in the correct order? using `limits` is key here I think. The error ist just in the key line orientation, not in the order of keys, right? I couldn't figure this one out, sorry!

Comment: Just saw that to solve the orientation of lines in the key, you might have to use `grid` editing functions, but it looks quite complicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954248/how-to-change-the-orientation-of-the-key-of-a-legend-in-ggplot. Good luck!